# Show elements of where clause that are not present in table without using union

Tags: sql, union, where-clause

```
select * from tblCustomer where CustomerName in ('A','B','C','Y','Z')
```

Suppose customer A, B & C are present in tblCustomer.

So, I want an output Y, Z in SQL. The customers name those are not present in tblCustomer without using union clause.

Comment: Create a table for ('A','B','C','Y','Z'), do select from that table where name not in tblCustomer.

Comment: ('A','B','C','Y','Z') are dynamic values it may contain up to 200 values. So, how i create table for dat

Comment: Tag dbms used. (The answer may depend on dbms product used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of SQL Server you can use Table Value Constructor introduced in version 2008.

```
select n as CustomerName from (values('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('Y'),('Z')) a(n)
left join tblCustomer c
 on a.n = c.customerName
 where c.customerName is null
```

The query return :

```
CustomerName
-------
    Y
    Z
```

**EDIT:**
You can always use function that returns table-values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListToTable]( @ValueList varchar( 2000 ) )
 RETURNS @ValuesTable TABLE ( Value varchar(80) )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
    @ValueSeparator varchar(1),
    @ValueSeparatorIndex int

SET @ValueSeparator = ',';

SET @ValueList = LTRIM( @ValueList )

SET @ValueSeparatorIndex = CHARINDEX ( @ValueSeparator, @ValueList );

WHILE @ValueSeparatorIndex > 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ValuesTable( Value ) VALUES(  SUBSTRING( @ValueList, 1, @ValueSeparatorIndex - 1 ) );

    SET @ValueList  = LTRIM( SUBSTRING( @ValueList , @ValueSeparatorIndex + 1, LEN(@ValueList ) - @ValueSeparatorIndex ) );

    SET @ValueSeparatorIndex = CHARINDEX ( @ValueSeparator, @ValueList );
END

IF LEN(@ValueList) > 0 
    INSERT INTO @ValuesTable( Value ) VALUES( @ValueList  );

RETURN
END
```

After that you can use it in below way:

```
select A.Value as CustomerName from ListToTable('A,B,C,X,Y') A
left join tblCustomer c
 on a.Value = c.customerName
 where c.customerName is null
```

Comment: How can we pass values using temp variable?

Comment: @chaitra Try to use function simply. I edited my answer.